# Необходимо , чтобы с помощью JS плавно появлялся у фона элемента градиент и плавно исчезал. Никак не могу свойство transition добавить с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, background, transition

**Html** -код:

```
<div class="process__card">
  <div class="process__content">
    <div class="process__lable">01<span>Consultation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="process__plus"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="process__subcontent process__subcontent_hidden">
    <hr>
    <div class="process__descrp">During the initial consultation, we will discuss your business goals and objectives, target audience, and current marketing efforts. This will allow us to understand your needs and tailor our services to best fit your requirements.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**-код:

```
    .process{
        padding-top: 140px;
        &__wrapper{
            display: flex;
            margin: 0 auto;
            flex-direction: column;
            gap:30px;
            width: 1234px;
        }
        &__card{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            background-color:#F3F3F3;
            height: 159px;
            border-radius:45px;
            border: 1px solid #191A23;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 #191A23;
            transition: 0.5s all;
            &_active{
                height: 279px;
            }
```

**JS**-код:

```
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.process__card');
card.forEach(cardItem => {
  cardItem.addEventListener('mouseover', animationBackround);
  cardItem.addEventListener('mouseout', animationBackround);
});

function animationBackround(event) {
  const eventType = event.type;

  const target = event.target.closest('.process__card');

  if (!target) return;

  if (eventType === 'mouseover') {
    let color1 = getRandomColor();
    let color2 = getRandomColor();
    target.style.background = `linear-gradient(45deg, ${color1}, ${color2})`;
  }

  if (eventType === 'mouseout') {
    target.style.background = 'none';
  }

}

function getRandomColor() {
  const letters = '01234567890ABCDEF';
  let color = "#";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }

  return color;
}
```